# How to read values inside an object using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation, metrics

I am calling REST API to get some metric data on azure resource. Below is the command,

$restcall = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $headers. Here is the output of the rest call.
[image]

After the above command I am trying to capture the values inside data. Below is the command to print "Data".

$object = $restcall.value.timeseries.data

The rest call runs on loop and provide different set of result in the data section. Here are few output of each loop. The timestamp is constant but the other value gets changed on every loop. How can I capture the 2nd value with their value?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the complete code which I am using:

```
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subId
#variable:
$metricname = "GeneratedTokens", "TokenTransaction","ProcessedPromptTokens", "Latency"
$aggtype = "Total", "Average", "Maximum"
$timespan = "2023-12-25T11:05:00.000Z/2024-02-14T11:05:00.000Z"

#Get OpenAI accounts
$res = Get-AzCognitiveServicesAccount
$openaiAcc = $res | Where-Object {$_.Endpoint -match 'openai.azure.com/'}

#generate bearer token:
$accesstoken = (Get-AzAccessToken).Token
$headers = @{   
 'Authorization' = "Bearer $accesstoken"
}

foreach($openai in $openaiAcc){
$openaiId = $openai.id
$subscriptionId = $openaiId.split('/')[2]
$RGName = $openai.ResourceGroupName
    foreach($metric in $metricname){
       Write-Host "the metric name is $metric"
           foreach($agg in $aggtype){
                    $url = "https://management.azure.com/$openaiId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?timespan=$timespan&metricnames=$metric&aggregation=$agg&api-version=2023-10-01&interval=FULL"
                    $restcall = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $url -Headers $headers
                    $object = $restcall.value.timeseries.data
           }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you actually converting the output to Json with `ConvertTo-Json` or is it just to show how the output looks like?

Comment: the `data` node is an array, use an array indexer: `$restcall.value.timeseries.data[1]`

Comment: Can you give your input and expected output in words/text and not as images?

Comment: Provide your Rest API URl and Headers too

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes I used ConvertTo-Json just to show the proper output so my question will be understandable.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I Tried your step but its not working. Please send me a screenshot if you have any.

Comment: @SubhransuSekhar, I have answered below, please check if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here are few output of each loop. The timestamp is constant but the other value gets changed on every loop. How can I capture the 2nd value with their value?

I have got value with timeStamp and total:

[image]

I have used below script to get second value:

```
$rithvalue=(Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com/").token          
$uri = "https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/b83c1ed/resourceGroups/AI/providers/Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts/aiud9/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01"
$headers1 = @{
    "Authorization" = "Bearer $rithvalue"
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}  
$rithtest = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $uri -Headers $headers1 
$rithobj = $rithtest.value.timeseries.data 
foreach ($rithobj in $rithobj) {
    foreach ($key in $rithobj.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($key.Name -ne "timestamp") {
            $keyName1 = $key.Name
            $value1 = $key.Value
            Write-Output "$keyName1 : $value1"
        }
}
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: I have pasted complete code in the description. If you see I am using 3 different aggregation type and I am getting different aggregation type in the data section. which is where I am facing issue to capture the aggragation type name and its value.

Comment: Yeah, which ever aggregation you use,```$rithobj = $rithtest.value.timeseries.data 
foreach ($rithobj in $rithobj) {
    foreach ($key in $rithobj.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($key.Name -ne "timestamp") {
            $keyName1 = $key.Name
            $value1 = $key.Value
            Write-Output "$keyName1 : $value1"
        }
}
}```
script matters, I have got answer for diferrent aggregation also, try using my script, you will get expected result. In script i have not mentioned just total, I have used Key.Name and Key.Value

Comment: Yes, Its working...Thanks for your quick turnaround.